# Sort multidimensional array based on another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have one array `($sort)` that looks like:

```
  [1]=>16701

  [2]=>16861

  [3]=>16706
```

And an array `($images)`, which looks like:

```
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["href"]=> string(35) "mystring"
    ["url"]=>  string(67) "mystring2"
    ["didascalia"]=> string(29) "mystring3"
    ["id"]=> 16861
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["href"]=> string(35) "mystring"
    ["url"]=>  string(70) "mystring2"
    ["didascalia"]=> string(37) "mystring3"
    ["id"]=> 16706
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["href"]=> string(35) "mystring"
    ["url"]=>  string(66) "mystring2"
    ["didascalia"]=> string(24) "mystring3"
    ["id"]=> 16701
  }
```

I need to sort `$images`, based on value `"id"`, using `$sort`.
So my result should be

```
[0]=>
array(4) {
  ["href"]=> string(35) "mystring"
  ["url"]=>  string(66) "mystring2"
  ["didascalia"]=> string(24) "mystring3"
  ["id"]=> 16701
}

[1]=>
array(4) {
  ["href"]=> string(35) "mystring"
  ["url"]=>  string(67) "mystring2"
  ["didascalia"]=> string(29) "mystring3"
  ["id"]=> 16861
}

[2]=>
array(4) {
  ["href"]=> string(35) "mystring"
  ["url"]=>  string(70) "mystring2"
  ["didascalia"]=> string(37) "mystring3"
  ["id"]=> 16706
}
```

How can I do it?
I tried using multisort, array_map but without success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you already have the ids in the desired sort order, the only barrier to sorting `$images` efficiently is the inability to immediately fetch an image given its id. So let's fix that by reindexing `$images` to use the id as the array key using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (don't get thrown by the name, it can also be used for reindexing):

```
// array_column is only available in PHP 5.5+
$images = array_column($images, null, 'id');
```

After this it's trivial to get a sorted array:

```
$sortedImages = [];
foreach ($sort as $id) {
    $sortedImages[] = $images[$id];
}
```

For PHP < 5.5 you can substitute the `array_column` reindexing with this:

```
$imageIds = array_map(function($i) { return $i['id']; }, $images);
$images = array_combine($imageIds, $images);
```

Alternatively you can get an [implementation written in PHP](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column) by the author of `array_column` himself.

Comment: I honestly didn't understand your solution, but it works, so thanks. 
I only had to substitute `$sortedImages = [];` with `$sortedImages = array();` because it gave me an error.

Comment: @topoftheforts: Was it the reindexing part or the loop part that was unclear? The `[]` error happened because that's the new (compact) array literal syntax introduced with PHP 5.4, while you seem to be on 5.3.

Comment: The reindexing, but I should check for the two functions you used before asking for an explanation, so don't worry, it's just my ignorance :)
Ok clear about the error! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$final = array();

foreach ($sort as $key) {
   foreach ($images as $img) {
      if($img['id'] == $key) {
         $final[] = $img;
      }
   }
}

print_r($final);
```

Comment: This is not a bad solution, but I was looking for something better in terms of performance. In my example there are three elements, but my real array has ~20. So this would mean ~400 iterations, too much.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 7+, it's possible to sort the input array directly and in-place according to the other described by the other array using [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and an anonymous comparison function that employs the [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op)

```
<?php
$sort = [16701, 16861, 16706];
$images = ...; // input array


// Create assoc array mapping the IDs in $sort to their desired sorted position.
$idOrder = array_combine($sort, range(0, count($sort)-1));

// Sort $images in-place according to the 'id' key, using the order
// described by $idOrder.
usort($images, function ($left, $right) use ($idOrder) {
    return $idOrder[$left['id']] <=> $idOrder[$right['id']];
});
```